# xfce: How to align icons on right side of desktop?

Tags: linux-mint, xfce, desktop-environment, xubuntu, thunar

How can I align icons on the right side of the desktop in Xfce?

In the settings I opted to hide all default icons on my desktop, but only icons of minimized windows of the current settion I let appear. I use the default file manager of Xubuntu & Linux Mint Xfce: Thunar.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality was added in xfdesktop version 4.13.3. You need at least that version or upgrade to [Xubuntu 20.04](https://xubuntu.org/news/xubuntu-20-04-released/) which introduced Xfce 4.14 by default.